# How to get Jenkins lastBuild API working with multi-branch pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I've had no problems getting last build details out of Jenkins in the past, but I've struck a weirdly-configured corporate environment, where the API urls are structured like this:

```
https://example.com/job/group-name/job/project-name/api/json
```

I can find the last build for a specific branch in this heirarchy:

```
https://example.com/job/group-name/job/project-name/job/branch-name/lastBuild/api/json
```

But how to get the last build of a project regardless of branch has defied all my efforts so far.

I can tell you that the obvious (and all non-obvious variations that I've tried) truly, seriously don't work. For instance, this is a complete failure:

```
https://example.com/job/group-name/job/project-name/lastBuild/api/json
```

And returns "This page isn’t working **example.com** redirected you too many times."

I'm guessing that the multiple copies of /job/ in the working URLs are a symptom of an unusual structure, so if anyone has any ideas I'm all ears!